# Magento 2.1 product view page

Tags: magento

I'm working on magento 2.1 ..
If I add content to product see picture ---> [Click for photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV9Cg.jpg)

How can I change product view page?

Where is the phtml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2 no longer uses a formal view.phtml file for the product view. It is all controlled with XML to load lots of individual template files.

You will find the layout in;

```
/app/design/frontend/[theme maker]/[theme name]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

If your theme is using a base theme as a fallback, for example the Magento/Blank theme, copy the file from that theme to your own theme's path.